# How to increase logical volume from disc space

Tags: linux

I have RHEL7 server where logical volume is 100% full. I have enough space in dick called "**sdc**" . Please suggest possible way to increase logical volume with out loosing data

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                             2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda                             8:0    0   250G  0 disk 
├─sda1                          8:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                          8:2    0 249.8G  0 part 
  ├─rootvg-lv_swap            253:0    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rootvg-lv_root-real       253:1    0 247.7G  0 lvm  
    ├─rootvg-lv_root          253:2    0 247.7G  0 lvm  /
    ├─rootvg-snap_lv_root     253:4    0 247.7G  0 lvm  
    └─rootvg-backsnap_lv_root 253:6    0 247.7G  0 lvm  
sdb                             8:16   0   100G  0 disk 
├─rootvg-snap_lv_root-cow     253:3    0  91.3G  0 lvm  
│ └─rootvg-snap_lv_root       253:4    0 247.7G  0 lvm  
└─rootvg-backsnap_lv_root-cow 253:5    0   8.7G  0 lvm  
  └─rootvg-backsnap_lv_root   253:6    0 247.7G  0 lvm  
sdc                             8:32   0   130G  0 disk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's the whole point of LVM: you can resize your logical volumes as far as your free space in your volume group suffices, and you can add arbitrarily many block devices as physical volume to your volume group.

So:

1. Make sdc a physical volume: `pvcreate /dev/sdc`
2. Add sdc as backing storage to your volume group: `vgextend rootvg /dev/sdc`
3. resize your logical volume (e.g. increase size by 50 GB): `lvresize -r -L +50G  rootvg/your-logicalk-volumen-name`

Aside from answering your question:
You have a lot of things going on in your system, including LVM snapshots. So, this looks quite like an expert setup, and you might need to read `man lvm` and adjacent manpages to understand that.

Comment: When I do "lvresize -r -L +100G rootvg/lv_root" Snapshot origin volumes can be resized only while inactive: try lvchange -an

Comment: I'm by defaults using lvextend instead of lvresize the options are the same.

Comment: lvextend -l +100%free rootvg/lv_root
  Snapshot origin volumes can be resized only while inactive: try lvchange -an

Comment: I am not able to resolve snapshot related error.. is there any other solution like create separate files system and make symbolic link to the original filesystem .

Comment: no, you need to understand how your complex LVM setup works to extend your complex LVM setup. There's really no way around it.